# Software to force installer/setup to run silently?

Tags: windows, command-line, installer

I am looking for a software which can force/silent most of the major installation wizards in order to install the software without any user interaction during the installation process.

I understand this normally works for installers which are supporting silent installs (MSI/InstallShield), but I'm talking about these which doesn't.

For instance when run from the command-line as:

```
silencer.exe setup.exe
```

it will install the program without any user interaction by suppressing any window popups by accepting automatically Terms/Licenses and other required fields. Or some similar idea.

Something similar to `yes` on Linux, but for Windows GUI. This can be achieved by writing VBScript, but I'm looking for some universal solution if exists.

Comment: That would highly depend on the installer type, the permissions required, and whether or not the user has a sandboxing program. It works on linux because package installation is generally always the same. On Windows, it varies a lot by application. I imagine such a solution would work well with simple self-extracting installers, but not as good with custom installers that come with bundled Adware/Crapware or those that require elevated permissions

Comment: I would take a look at this from SuperUser, http://superuser.com/questions/31811/how-do-i-create-an-unattended-installer-for-various-applications-in-windows. If I were you, I would create an AutoIt script that would look for words like "next", "yes", "terms", and so on and click them (That should install most installers). You can launch programs silently (hidden) with AutoIt by using the command, "Run ( 'program' , 'workingdir', @SW_HIDE).

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I'll try AutoIt. I hope it'll work under Wine, as I'm actually aiming to do the Windows app install on headless Linux server, so I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I digged out few solutions:

- [`msiexec`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/227091) for [Microsoft Installer packages (MSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), for instance:

  ```
  msiexec /i /path/to/install.msi /l*v out.log /qn
  ```

  where:

  > `/qn` : Displays no user interface.

  or just run `msiexec /?` for help. See: [How do I automate an MSI installs?](https://superuser.com/q/246639/87805)

  However [`/q` can be disabled by the designers](https://superuser.com/questions/246639/how-do-i-automate-an-msi-installs/246642#comment256886_246646).
- [WPKG](http://wpkg.org/) - automated software deployment, upgrade and removal program for Windows.

  > It can install MSI, InstallShield, PackagefortheWeb, Inno Setup, Nullsoft, other software installers or .exe packages, .bat and .cmd scripts and similar
- [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)/[NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/) - Windows Installation Customizer ([How to enable Unattended setup?](http://www.nliteos.com/faq.html#Q25)).
- [Universal Silent Switch Finder (USSF)](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Universal-Silent-Switch-Finder.shtml)

  > Utility designed to help you find the silent switch in the applications that you want to install. If you want to deploy software without the user intervention you can use this tool in order to run the installer silently.
- Finally you can consider contacting the developer of the application in order to ask for a silent installation or alternatively check the [Application Switches forum](http://www.msfn.org/board/forum/80-application-installs/).
- Using X server on your [Windows](https://superuser.com/q/119792/87805)/Linux workstation with X11 forwarding, run the app under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) emulator and do some [scripting/hacks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219460/21471).

Alternatively check the following applications which can monitor your software installation, and then can create a silent-install package of the files and registry changes that occurred during the installation:

- [WinInstall LE](http://www.scalable.com/it-asset-management-products/wininstall/) [README](http://support.attachmate.com/manuals/wininstall/9.0/LE/ReadMe.html) (Freeware) (and its 'Discover Wizard')

  > It is a low-cost companion repackaging tool.
- [InstallRite](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/InstallRite.shtml) (Freeware), (see other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/installrite/)).

  > Is a tool that can help you setup or update the same application on multiple computers by recreating the installation settings and generating a software clone image. Designed to help you save time, the program can also detect the system configuration changes due to software installing.
- [Windows Post-Install Wizard (WPI)](http://www.wpiw.net/) with Autoit scipts.
- [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/) (Freeware) and [Collection of scripts](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/20197-autoit-script-collection-contributions-only/) from forum members.
- [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) and its UniExtract Installer

  > Universal Extractor is a program designed to decompress and extract files from any type of archive.
- Symantec AI Snapshot (Included in [Symantec Ghost Corporate](http://www.symantec.com/en/uk/ghost-solution-suite/)).

  See: [Symantec Ghost AutoInstall (AI) FAQ](http://www.dynamicgeometry.com/Technical_Support/FAQ/Installation_and_Compatibility/Symantec_Ghost_AutoInstall_(AI).html)

  > You can also install AI Snapshot from CDStart.exe from your installation cd/files by selecting "Install Tools and Utilities" -> "Install AutoInstall"
- Create your own MSI installer via [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/) to match the criteria.

Other which I'm not sure if they're relevant (needs some 2nd opinion):

- [InstallPad](http://installpad.philisoft.com/), [Ketarin](https://ketarin.org/), [Ninite](https://ninite.com/), [ITNinja](http://www.itninja.com/)

If all above fails, then you've to write either VBScript which [launches the app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22580889/55075) (`WshShell.RUN`) or for more advanced solution you can (or ask somebody to) write some wrapper app to inject into the process by using for example [DosBox Injector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbi/) (some [code sample](https://github.com/kenorb/knockout)).

> DosBox Injector injects itself into active Windows applications and redirecting all DOS executables to DosBox before start.

See also the following links:

- [Unattended Windows Guide](http://unattended.msfn.org/)
- [How do I create an unattended installer for various applications in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/31811/87805) at SU
- [Automatic install of software in Windows XP](https://serverfault.com/q/58816/130437) at SF

Comment: Nice, neat list!